# How to get the only the 2nd best score in MySqL? not the others

Tags: php, mysql

i have one server whit minigames, and i have a problem whit my database, i need to get in query of mysql only the 2nd best score name.. can anyone help-me?
this is my database:

DATA_BASE

```
name  | kills 
------+------
Leon  | 22    
Andy  | 14    
Brian | 8
```

i need to get just Andy name and kills from Andy!
code:

```
"SELECT * FROM `DATA_BASE` ORDER BY `kills` DESC"
```

please help-me! can i use limit to do this? what should i do? Thks

Comment: did you not even Google "limit mysql"? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: you're also going to need another clause and method

Comment: use the `LIMIT` of mysql in your query

Comment: *"need to get in query of mysql only the 2nd best score name"* - being `14` I see, is that correct? Are you looking at comments or are you not bothering? Edit: Ok, I see you're not bothering.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i know now what to do ;D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
SELECT * FROM DATA_BASE ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

`LIMIT 1` limits the number of rows selected and `OFFSET 1` offsets the rows by 1 resulting in only second row being selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT name FROM DATA_BASE ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

This should return only the second best, because we want 1 option (the second number) and we want to offset it by 1 (the first number)

Comment: I use this, but the game thinks that LIMIT should be LIMIT of kills

Comment: MySQL doesn't use limit to evaluate greater than or less than, it limits the number of returns. It's possible you have another problem in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` keyword like as follows:

```
 SELECT * FROM DATA_BASE ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that.
Should limit to one 1 record and start on record 2.

```
"SELECT * FROM DATA_BASE ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM DATA_BASE ORDER BY kills DESC LIMIT 2) AS DB ORDER BY kills LIMIT 1;
```

We can do the same without using LIMIT by using MAX native function:

```
SELECT MAX(kills) FROM DATA_BASE WHERE kills NOT IN ( SELECT Max(kills) FROM DATA_BASE);
```

which is quite easier compared to earlier one